# Parse not logging out

Tags: android, parse-platform, logout

i'm trying to logout my current user but its not working. can anyone tell me what i might be doing wrong?

```
 public void logout(View view){

        // do stuff with the user
    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
       ParseUser.logOut();
      currentUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();



       if(currentUser==null) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

       }
       else

       {
           // show the signup or login screen
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"user not logged out ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }


        Intent logout= new Intent(this, start_page.class);
       startActivity(logout);




}
```

The toast i make keeps saying "user not logged out" can anyone tell what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you do `currentUser.logOut();` instead?

Comment: its still not working :/

Answer (score 1):

Never mind i fixed it. in my parse application class, i had automatic user enabled. i took it out and now its working perfectly. thanks for the suggestions though

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseUser.logOut();
currentUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

to

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
currentUser.logOut();
currentUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
```

But I have to say, I'm not 100% sure that `ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` returns null as you expect when no one is logged in. Can you provide a reference for where you got this code from?

Comment: I tried that too but the toast still says user not logged out. I wanted to keep the home stream running if the user is not logged out and start the login activity if the current user is null. I wa trying that even after i logout and close the app and start again, the home activity opened and it didn't switch to login activity. that's why i wanted to check if my logout code is even working or not. I wrote the code myself just for debugging purposes

Comment: ParseUser class has a static instance that is the currentUser, and logOut(), logOutInBackground() methods are static methods, so your solution doesn't really change anything.